# get msisdn in FirefoxOS

Tags: javascript, mozilla, firefox-os, msisdn

i'm trying to retrieve MSISDN in a FirefoxOS phone.
i'm doing the extraction of other data, so i have many permissions on my manifest.webapp:

```
"permissions":{
 "mobileid": {},
 "mobilenetwork": {},
 "mobileconnection": {},
 "open-remote-window": {},
 "telephony": {},
 "wifi-manage": {}
}
```

my problem is the phone gives me nothing about the MozMobileICCInfo interface :(

the property i'm looking for is MozMobileICCInfo.msisdn

i'm testing my app as "certified". can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

> Powerful and dangerous APIs are **not available** to third-party apps.

Only **internal apps** can access the general Telephony APIs on [[image]firefox-os](/questions/tagged/firefox-os), because they are intended for system-level apps and default apps created by Mozilla/operators/OEMs.

Check the [Permissions Table for Internal (Certified) Apps (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/App_permissions#Internal_(Certified)_app_permissions).

However, it is recommended to use the [Mobile Identity API](https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebAPI/MobileIdentity), to obtain a verified phone number (MSISDN):

```
"permissions": { "mobileid": {} }
```

Implemented and enabled in [[image]firefox-os](/questions/tagged/firefox-os) `>= 2.0` and allowed for certified and privileged apps.

Comment: as i already stated i already use "mobileid" permission. What you say is nothing new. also i think i know how the permissions movie goes also.
I don't want want to use Mobile Identity API, but my question is intended about MozMobileICCInfo. anyway thanks for your time :)